# результат поиска с вложенностью таблиц

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

есть две таблицы:`FilmEntity` и `ActorEntity`.
`ActorEntity` связана с `FilmEntity` с отношением **многие к одному**, так как у одного фильма может быть много актеров.
при запросе фильма в базе через *ORM* на выходе получаю вот такие данные:

```
{
    id: 123, // id фильма
    actors: [ // массив актеров, которые играют в этом фильме
        {
           id: 23423423,
           id: 4234234234
        }
    ]
}
```

здесь всё отлично и красиво.
далее я успешно проиндексировал свою базу через *Sphinx*, и при поиске одного фильма получаю ответ из двух записей:

```
[
    {
        film_id: 123,
        actor_id: 23423423
    },
    {
        film_id: 123,
        actor_id: 4234234234
    }
]
```

**Вопрос**: как мне сделать, чтобы *Sphinx* отдавал такую красивую вложенность в одном объекте, как и *ORM*?
Буду рад любому комментарию, совету, статье на эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. индексировать так, чтобы actor_id был MVA или JSON атрибутом, а один документ - один фильм, а не пара фильм-актёр
2. использовать группировку по film_id и GROUP_CONCAT(), правда тогда id актёров будут строкой и нужно будет в приложении разделить на элементы

Comment: я как раз использую Ваш продукт, а не чистый *Sphinx*. пользуясь случаем хочу выразить благодарность за Ваш труд